# What are these resistors and capacitors doing in this audio CODEC circuit?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, resistors, audio, filter

I'm implementing the VS1053 Audio CODEC IC on a PCB design where I will be using it along with a class D amplifier that will connect to a pair of 8 ohm speakers. I'm looking at SparkFun's MP3 Player Shield dev board for guidance on drafting the schematic. What I'm having trouble understanding is what the series resistors and capacitors (R7, C11, and R6, C10) are doing. They look like an RC snubber circuit, but I'm not sure what purpose they serve.

I also don't understand what R21 and R22 are doing. I can see that the SPKR_L and SPRK_R are the output of a high pass filter, but I don't understand why R21 and R22 are being used. I'm looking for some guidance on why these components are used, why these values, and if I need them in my PCB design.

[Datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/VS1053B.pdf?_gl=1*hwkf6t*_ga*NTYzMjQwOTgyLjE2OTA4NDA3Mjk.*_ga_T369JS7J9N*MTcwMTUzOTgxOC4xMS4xLjE3MDE1Mzk4NjYuMTIuMC4w) and [SparkFun Dev Board Schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/MP3%20Shield_v15.pdf?_gl=1*1re8g5j*_ga*NTYzMjQwOTgyLjE2OTA4NDA3Mjk.*_ga_T369JS7J9N*MTcwMTY1OTgxMS4xNC4xLjE3MDE2NTk4MjEuNTAuMC4w)

[image]

Comment: C17 and C18 are DC-blocking capacitors.

Comment: It's not a great design since the 470 ohm output impedance will make driving low impedance headphones difficult. It's probably just a cheap part.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobel_network#Zobel_networks_and_loudspeaker_drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Audio output from this chip is powerful-enough to drive headphones or earbuds, but is a bit feeble driving loudspeakers directly.
It can also drive an amplifier which in turn drives headphones or loudspeakers - this is the case outlined by OP's question.

A following amplifier often expects line-level input amplitude, and appears as a high-resistance load (often 10k ohm or more). So the Zobel network (R7, C11) can be left off.

Nominal audio output voltage is 1.85V peak-to-peak. One might regard this level as "full-amplitude". The amplifier to follow will likely have voltage gain: boosting 1.85V p-p to a larger amplitude (and power) for loudspeakers. A powerful amplifier might have a voltage gain of 50. Since OP includes no specs for the proposed Class-D amplifier, one cannot do a complete design, choosing component values.
However, it might be wise to include a place for R21, R15 (a resistor divider) to allow for amplifier gain. R15 serves another purpose: "thump" attenuation if the amplifier is attached when all powered-up.
In the amplifier shown below, the resistor divider would consist of R1, R3, with R3 also serving as the "thump" resistor.

As with most audio interface, a coupling capacitor is required - 1uf should be sufficient to drive an amplifier having 10k input resistance. If an electrolytic capacitor is used for C1, C2, polarity shown accommodates the +1.6V bias of U1. Simple audio interface:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flBdbr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

An example design:
Let's assume two LM386 audio amplifiers, with +12V DC_Vcc supply.
Input resistance is GND-referenced with about 50k input resistance. These amplifiers have internal default (minimum) voltage gain of 20.
Amplifier output voltage might reach 6.5v p-p before distortion sets in, so with a gain of 20, input voltage of 0.325V p-p would be required...
Voltage divider network of R3/R1 is required to attenuate 1.85v p-p to 0.325v p-p. If we leave R1 at 470 ohms, R3 would be about 100 ohms. Thus, full amplitude would drive the speakers near to the distortion point. Note that total resistance of 570 ohms puts the high-pass corner frequency @ 279 Hz (somewhat too high for audio). In this case, increasing C1, C2 to 10uf would be appropriate.

Or, scale up R1, R3 to 4700 ohms and 1k ohm respectively, and keep C1 @ 1uf.

Answer (score 2):

> what the Series Resistor and Capacitors in (R7, C11, and R6, C10) are doing

They are called "Zobel network". Because the load is a motor (inductive load) the load impedance varies with frequency. These R-C pairs kinda "balance" or "stabilise" the load impedance seen by the driver.

> but I don't understand why R21 and R22 are being used.

The codec's output can be probably quite high. If you want to use headphones or similar small speakers with the IC, you may not want to drive them with that high levels. So the 470R (R21 / R22) works as an attenuator (e.g. for a 32 Ohm headphone speaker 470R brings almost a 1/15 attenuation which should be good enough). C17 (C18) is there for AC coupling.

Comment: For my application, the output audio signals from the codec are going to go directly to a Class D amplifier. Should I just take the Zobel network and put them on the speaker output of the amplifier, since I'm not using headphones?

Comment: @Jay Zobel network is required for inductive loads. Class-D amp's input is not inductive. But you want the Zobel network for class-D amp's outputs.

Answer (score 0):

> *What I'm having trouble understanding is what the Series Resistor and
> Capacitors in (R7, C11, and R6, C10) are doing*

Firstly, those components are specified in the [data sheet for the CODEC](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/VS1053B.pdf?_gl=1*hwkf6t*_ga*NTYzMjQwOTgyLjE2OTA4NDA3Mjk.*_ga_T369JS7J9N*MTcwMTUzOTgxOC4xMS4xLjE3MDE1Mzk4NjYuMTIuMC4w) (see the connection diagram on page 13 of the data sheet) so, if you are thinking of not using them, then this is not-advisable/not-optional.

I expect that they perform high frequency attenuation of unwanted signals from the CODEC outputs or prevent the output from becoming unstable at high frequencies.

> *I also don't understand what R21 and R22 are doing. I can see that the
> SPKR_L and SPRK_R are the output of a high pass filter, but I don't
> understand why R21 and R22 are being used.*

These resistors are not shown in the CODEC data sheet but, I suspect that SparkFun have included them to attenuate the signal levels to line levels (optional if you read the wording they have used): -

[image]

So, for instance, you can connect the outgoing terminal (JP1 or Jp3) directly to the LEFT output or, you can connect it (via the solder blob) to a line level version (via R21). Ditto for the other channel.